# NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error 500 19 183 0

Tags: asp.net, iis, configuration, firebug, fiddler

We've recently deployed an application to a Windows 2012 R2 Server running IIS8 production box that isn't rendering css or image files up to the browser.

It renders fine in development and validation, however when we put it into production we get an error (Firebug and Fiddler) of:

```
NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://website/app/masterpage.css
```

The IIS log entry looks like this:

```
2015-08-13 18:55:05 172.30.87.77 GET /app/masterpage.css - 80 - 172.25.69.111 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:33.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/33.0 http://website/app/Default.aspx 500 19 183 0
```

I've been searching the web to try and find similar issues and it seems that in order to drill down into this error, I might need to find an HRESULT code, however I cannot determine where this code would be found.

We've looked in the Windows EventViewer, however do not see any 500 Errors there for IIS and cannot see any HRESULT codes in Fiddler or Firebug.

I guess the other option would be to turn on FailedRequestTracing in IIS 8

Thanks for any guidance on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check MIME Types extension: .css MIME type: text/css added in your site entry/MIME Types.